# What are the applications of Mellin transforms?

Tags: calculus, integration, transformation, mellin-transform

I stumbled upon an integral transform called the Mellin transform, I found how it is defined but I don’t understand how this integral is supposed to converge, especially for positive values of n. Also, what are the applications of the Mellin transform, especially in pure maths ? And why is it defined this way, is it because of the gamma function ?

Comment: Are you interested in applied uses? Example: recovering parton distribution functions.

Comment: This [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform#Applications) article will give you a good idea of the mathematics behind the Melling transform and its applications in medicine and engineering.

Answer (score 3):

The Mellin transform is really "just" a different-coordinate version of Fourier transform, with coordinates changed by $x\to e^x$, mapping the real line "with addition" to the positive reals "with multiplication".

As with literal Fourier transform, the underlying point is that Mellin *inversion* (and/or Fourier inversion) expresses a given function as a superposition of eigenfunctions for the operator "differentiation" (or something close to it...)

Answer (score 2):

The Mellin transform is used to study functions that have power-law decay. It is defined as
$$
\mathcal{M}(f)(s) = \int_0^\infty f(x)x^{s-1}\,dx \tag{1}
$$
where $s=\sigma+it$ is a complex parameter. Its inverse is given by
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\sigma_0-i\infty}^{\sigma_0+i\infty} \mathcal{M}(f)(s)x^{-s}\,ds \tag{2}
$$
where $\sigma_0$ is a number such that the integral on the right of (2) converges.
For example, suppose $f$ is defined by $f(x) = x^{-\alpha}$ with $\alpha > 0$. Then
$$
\mathcal{M}(f)(s) = \int_0^\infty f(x)x^{s-1}\,dx = \int_0^\infty x^{-\alpha+s-1}\,dx = \Gamma(s-\alpha)
$$
where we have used $\Gamma(t) = \int_0^\infty x^{t-1}e^{-x}\,dx$ for $t > 0$.
Thus, the Mellin transform of $f$ is a meromorphic function with a pole of order $-\alpha$ at $s=\alpha$.
Note that $f$ is defined for $x > 0$, so the integral on the left of (1) converges if $\mathrm{Re}(s) > \alpha$.
The integral on the right of (2) converges if $\sigma_0 < \mathrm{Re}(s) < \alpha$.
The Mellin transform has many other applications in pure and applied mathematics.